# How to calculate total time the sensor is staic or dynamic?

Tags: esp8266

I have an accelerometer module, which is connected to a `esp8266`.

I've already taken the values when device is moving and static (read raw data from register).

Its given in the "If" condition, how can I calculate the total time (second or minute) when device is static or dynamic ?

```
#include <Ticker.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#include <MPU6050.h>
int  startTime=0,endTime=0;
int i=0;
int j=0;
double x;
double y;
int SCL_PIN=26; 
int SDA_PIN=25; 
MPU6050 mpu;
Ticker blinker;

void changeState()
{
Vector rawAccel =mpu.readRawAccel();

x =  rawAccel.XAxis;
y = rawAccel.YAxis;

if(x>250&&x<1000||y>64000)  // static values
 {
 i++;
 Serial.print("static");
  Serial.print("total time in second ");
 Serial.println(i);
 }

 if(x>900||y<500)    // dynamic values
 {
   j++;
   Serial.print("dynamic");
   Serial.print("total time in second");
   Serial.println(j);

 }

}


void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("Initialize MPU6050");

  while(!mpu.beginSoftwareI2C(SCL_PIN,SDA_PIN,MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS, MPU6050_RANGE_2G))
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid MPU6050 sensor, check wiring!");
    delay(500);
  }
 blinker.attach(.5, changeState);

}

void loop()
{

}
```

I tried this code, but some values are missing, any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Take the time in millis() at the entry point for deducting from the last time it existed the loop the difference in time (seconds) is the time its was either dynamic or static.

You can always change the data type of "sec", "i", "j" if you find any error.

```
#include <Ticker.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#include <MPU6050.h>
int  startTime=0,endTime=0;
uint32_t i=0;
uint32_t j=0;
double x;
double y;
int SCL_PIN=26; 
int SDA_PIN=25; 
MPU6050 mpu;
Ticker blinker;
uint32_t sec, secDiff = 0;

void changeState()
{
int sec1 = millis() / 1000;
Vector rawAccel =mpu.readRawAccel();

x =  rawAccel.XAxis;
y = rawAccel.YAxis;

if(x>250&&x<1000||y>64000)  // static values
 {
 i += (sec - secDiff) % 60;
 Serial.print("static");
  Serial.print("total time in second ");
 Serial.println(i);
 }

 if(x>900||y<500)    // dynamic values
 {
   j += (sec - secDiff) % 60;
   Serial.print("dynamic");
   Serial.print("total time in second");
   Serial.println(j);

 }
secDiff = sec1;
sec = millis() / 1000;
}


void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("Initialize MPU6050");

  while(!mpu.beginSoftwareI2C(SCL_PIN,SDA_PIN,MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS, MPU6050_RANGE_2G))
  {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid MPU6050 sensor, check wiring!");
    delay(500);
  }
 secDiff = millis()/1000;
 blinker.attach(.5, changeState);

}

void loop()
{

}
```

Comment: static and dynamic motion is detected but  i and j values become always  zero.??

Comment: Simply print the millis() without dividing it with 1000 and tell me the output. As i am thinking the result value is less then 1 and also try it using float/double instead of int.

Comment: So replace sec, sec1, i, j to float/double instead of int.

Comment: "millis() without dividing it with 1000"  sorry ..its still showing i and j values zero??

Comment: Have you tried float/double/uint32_t for sec.

Also try simple Serial.println(millis()); and tell me the results

Comment: Ok.. I will check

Comment: tried float/double/uint32_t  , second wise printing but both both sec, sec1 same value while printing

Comment: tried changing the value of i,j as well as sec and sec1 to float/double/uint32_t

Comment: Try the code i have made some change as you mentioned the sec and sec1 value are same so there is a secDiff that is taken while the code is running or simply the code run time taken.

Comment: If there is issue let me know